# How to change the path of infinitescroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I've recently installed the infinitescroll plugin in my website to load content easier but I've got a problem:

I've got a filter which orders all the posts by, for example, genre, data, country, etc when you select it in a list. It's made with ajax and the problem is that the path when you apply this filter must be different as firstly, so when it loads content, it loads posts without the filter applied, and what I need is to change the infinitescroll path when clicking to order the posts.

**Infinitescroll plugin:**

```
$('.catalogue').infiniteScroll({
      path: '.pagination__next', //it gets the href attribute from .pagination__next and of course it is changed in the html code when the filter is applied but in the js code is not.
      append: '.item',
      button: '.view-more-button',
     scrollThreshold: false,
      history: false,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a function to set the path like this

```
$('.catalogue').infiniteScroll({
    path: function(){
        return $('.pagination__next').attr('href');
    },
    append: '.item',
    button: '.view-more-button',
    scrollThreshold: false,
    history: false,
    });
```

Or you could apply any other logic you want in your path function to fit your needs.

Comment: Works as always without the applied filter but when you apply it it stops working. Weird

Comment: can you post the URLs that the scripts sends requests to, after the filter is applied? (You can get them from the Network tab in your console)

Comment: `/inicio?pagina='.$sig.'&order='.$_GET["order"].'&data='.$_GET["data"].'` that outputs `/inicio?pagina=2&order=&data=` in the first page (don't worry about order and data, in the main page they must be null)

Comment: that is the filtered URL or the normal one? Do the requests made to this URL or they go to a different one?

Comment: The normal one is that i've written above and when you apply the filter `order=` and `data=` get a string (for example genre, year for `order` & 2013, 2054, action for `data`)

Comment: ok, if it is not working you have to check on which URL the requests are made. If you are using Chrome press **Right Click** -> **Inspect Element** -> go to **Network Tab**, then scroll down to use the infinity scroller and a request should appear in that tab. You can view to which URL the requests are sent to and if the GET variables are sent correctly. Also make sure that your **/incicio** page use the **order** and **data** as GET parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163115/discussion-between-knetsi-and-ismael-quirantes).

Comment: Could u come back to the chat?